# How to add sendgrid mailer function in yii2?

Tags: yii2, sendgrid

I am trying to get the mail using sendgrid for the project in Yii 2 but it doesn't seem to work.Please any one tell me steps so that i could implement that on yii2.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39375794/2138791

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steps to send mail using sendgrid mailer function in yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373201/steps-to-send-mail-using-sendgrid-mailer-function-in-yii2)