# Steps to send mail using sendgrid mailer function in yii2?

Tags: yii2, sendgrid

I am trying to get the mail using sendgrid  in Yii 2 but it doesn't seem to work.Can any one tell me steps of sendgrid in yii2 .

Comment: Your question is very low quality. Please, add more info. Which extension are you using, how do you set up it, how do you call it, which error explicitly do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-sendgrid#yii-2-bryglen-sendgrid

Installation:

```
composer require --prefer-dist bryglen/yii2-sendgrid "*"
```

common/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'sendGrid' => [
        'class' => 'bryglen\sendgrid\Mailer',
        'username' => 'your_user_name',
        'password' => 'your password here',
        //'viewPath' => '@app/views/mail', // your view path here
    ],
    ...
],
```

To send an email, you may use the following code:

```
$sendGrid = Yii::$app->sendGrid;
$message = $sendGrid->compose('contact/html', ['contactForm' => $form]);
$message->setFrom('from@domain.com')
    ->setTo($form->email)
    ->setSubject($form->subject)
    ->send($sendGrid);
```

Comment: It is better to configure `mailer` component with `'class' => 'bryglen\sendgrid\Mailer'` due to 'Convention over configuration' paradigm, used in Yii